# PRE tag not working as it should

Tags: html

For PHP debugging I made myself a pre() function like this:

```
function pre($data)
{
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($data).'</pre>';
}
```

But it's not displaying line breaks as it should. By example, I get all this on one line:

`Template_model Object ( [id] => 1 [type] => 1 [shortname] => default [is_custom] => 0 [is_open] => 1 [options] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => background_color [value] => #6699CC [type] => 0 [campaign_id] => 8 [user_id] => 11 [template_id] => 1 ) )`

Some parts should have linebreaks. What am I doing wrong?

This may sound newb, but I can't understand what I do wrong when I've been using this for years.

Please not that I call my pre function before there is any other HTML displayed on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the `pre` before `print_r()` as `print_r()` handles its own output. Like this:

```
function pre($data) 
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

I am however not sure if it would preserve line-breaks if you use the optional parameter (specifying that you want it to return the output instead). Let's see [what codepad has to say about it](http://codepad.org/uEBsvLeN).

Comment: It working, and now I feel dumb haha. Thank you! Sometimes you look too much you get blond!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as... the answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Comment: There's a limit? Who would've known?!

Answer (score 4):

[`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) does not return the string, it echos to the screen itself (and returns TRUE)

If you pass `true` as a 2nd parameter, then it'll return a string.

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```